# No representation or empty representation in HTTP

Tags: rest, http, rfc, representation

In HTTP responses, is there a clear difference between a resource that has no representation and a resource that has a representation that is an empty string?

If so, how can I distinguish the two situations? Are there even multiple ways to express these?

Please provide references to the current IETF RFCs in your answers.

Comment: I'd send a `204 No Content` for the first, and a `200 OK` with an empty body for the second.

Comment: this is a kind of a philosophical question. Is it reasonable to have a resource with no representation exposed? What's good in exposing something that shouldn't return any representation? Shouldn't you return a 404 not found instead?

Comment: For example it seems that the media types of `multipart` type are not intended to represent an empty list. So if I request a `multipart` representation of a collection resource that is empty, I suppose the right thing to do would be to indicate that the resource exists but does not have a representation at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In HTTP responses, is there a clear difference between a resource that has no representation and a resource that has a representation that is an empty string?

HTTP has a specified way to describe a representation (a byte array) that is zero bytes long: [204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.  Metadata in the response header fields refer to the target resource and its selected representation after the requested action was applied.

This is sometimes used in web apis to describe "flag" resources.  The [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#check-if-you-are-starring-a-repository) uses 204/404 to indicate the presence/absence of a star.

That said, your ability to distinguish a null representation from an empty representation is going to depend on the media type of that representation; client and server need to understand the message payload the same way, and they communicate that bit of meta-data via the [Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header.

For example, [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2) specifies that the `application/json` representation is a `JSON-text` is a `value` (surrounded by optional white space), where valid productions of `value` include a `string` or a literal `null`.  So those are easy to distinguish

On the other hand, if the content type is `text/plain`... well, a zero length byte array is the natural way to represent an empty text file, so I would expect an empty string to have the same representation.  I have no idea at all what representation other than a zero length byte array would serve for "no representation", so I guess that case isn't distinguishable.

If I had to come up with a way to report zero length representations that are *different*, in some ineffable way... I suppose I'd encode the information in the content-type itself, taking media types from either the [vendor tree](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.2) or the [personal tree](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.3).  I'd feel vaguely slimy in doing so, and would worry about the implications on caches, conneg, and so forth.

It's not a problem I want to have.